# possible type of database that uses dat, idx files

Tags: database, delphi, odbc

i have an application that was written in delphi it is fairly recent, running on win32
i want to hook into the database with odbc but i am unsure which database driver to use

the directory with the database has
.dat
.idx
files for each table

it is a standalone database not client server (as far as i can tell)
any ideas what type of database this may be so i can find a driver

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it's [DBISAM](http://www.elevatesoft.com/prodinfo?action=view&product=dbisam&no=1), and because the application written in Delphi it more likely to be DBISAM.

and you can download Server Administration Utility from their site  (free), so you can open these  dat files and check if it DBISAM or not.

Comment: Also, they have an ODBC driver if it does match. Be sure to open a copy of the files in case it is an old version which would cause them to be upgraded and break compatibility with the existing app.

Comment: it was dbisam, i have downloaded the odbc driver and using the readonly option. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately .DAT and .IDX are common to many different database engines, including Foxpro/DBase, Advantage, Informix, DBISAM, and even custom solutions.  Since it is a fairly recent Delphi application, I would guess [Advantage](http://www.extendedsystems.co.uk/web/content.aspx?key=F4865DD0C39A3D7CEDCC29852332B93B) first.  I believe the Advantage drivers read/write the Foxpro/DBase format, so I would try a DBase driver (read only of course) and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly Informix, although there's no guarantee of that. If you look at the first dozen or two bytes with a hex editor does anything jump out at you?

Edit: See https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5208-6230-0.html?forumID=101&threadID=224583&start=0.

Comment: yea, could be Informix files. Standard Engine, is what it was called back in the day. If the file names are like "yourtab123.dat/.idx" that would be suspiciously like Informix. But it's been so long, I couldn't say for sure today.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an [Informix](http://www.informix.com) DB. Check out the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113582/attaching-informix-dat-and-idx-files).